# How to pull from repo and push to anonther

Tags: git, repository

I have basic skills in git + repository. 
How can I pull the updates from a official GitHub Repository to my laptop, merge my features there with the new updates and push all to my own repo?
Is there a simple solution without always typing the urls of two different repos in parameters? I never want to push my changes to the official repo.

Thanks.

http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/52972,unbenanntHW3BS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Git supports managing multiple repos out-of-box. Fetch and push can both take the target repository as a parameter.

To add remote repositories execute:

```
git remote add [name of remote] https://url.to/remote
```

List remotes using:

```
git remote -v
```

Finally fetching and pushing from a specific repo:

```
git fetch [remote name]
git push [remote] [branch]
```

To fetch changes from one repo and push them to another pull changes from one remote, checkout source branch and push the changes to destination repo.

Comment: Please consider giving some details in your answer from the link you've posted. Just put a code snippet, a quote, anything.